# ASP.NET: How do I check to see if my ListViewItemEventArgs is a ListItem or not?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, listview, repeater

When working with Repeaters I'm able to check and see if my ItemType in my ItemDataBound is an  actual item by using the following code...

```
If e.Item.ItemType = UI.WebControls.ListItemType.Item Or e.Item.ItemType = UI.WebControls.ListItemType.AlternatingItem Then ...
```

How can I do this same thing with my ListView? I attempted the check the same way above but no luck. The If statement never gets executed.

Thanks!

**EDIT**

```
  Private Sub ListView_ItemDataBound(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListViewItemEventArgs) Handles ListView.ItemDataBound

        If e.Item.ItemType = UI.WebControls.ListItemType.Item Or e.Item.ItemType = UI.WebControls.ListItemType.AlternatingItem Then

            'This section never executes...

        End If
```

Comment: Could you post the ItemDataBound handler source? Might just be something simple in there...

Comment: @DavidW, yes one moment... it's up!

Comment: Are you sure the event itself fires?

Comment: Yup, it actually executes the IF statement for every row in my data source.

Comment: What IS being returned in the e.Item.ItemType expression, then?? Curious..

Comment: I think you're using the wrong enumeration. Check out the ListViewItemType enumeration...might well fix your problem. :)  Docs at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb299031.aspx

Comment: Thanks! can you post answer when you get a moment so i can credit it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you're just using the wrong enumeration. Try the `ListItemViewType` enumeration and that should solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you want

```
 if (e.Item.ItemType == ListViewItemType.DataItem)
 {
ListItem li = (ListItem)e.Item;
```

Instead of:

```
    If e.Item.ItemType = UI.WebControls.ListItemType.Item Or e.Item.ItemType = UI.WebControls.ListItemType.AlternatingItem Then
```

This was taken from the docs here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listview.itemdatabound.aspx

Sorry fort the C# syntax but it should point you in the right direction.